# MYSQL LOAD DATA INFILE - Errcode 2

Tags: java, mysql, sqlexception

I exported a java project as a jar in windows and uploaded the jar to a linux server. On executing the jar I get to see "C:" being appended in the beginning of the file path. Here's the log :

```
Query : LOAD data infile "/home/user/java_correlation_engine/CorrelationFiles/temp.txt" ignore into table logical_mapping fields terminated by '|' lines terminated by '\n'

java.sql.SQLException: File 'C:\home\user\java_correlation_engine\CorrelationFiles\temp.txt' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
```

The query looks exactly how I wanted it to be but it throws SQLException.

Comment: How is the query built in Java ?

Comment: query = "load data infile $tempPath ignore into table . . . ";  query = query.replace("$tempPath","\""+path of the file+"\"");

Comment: So how is $tempPath constructed ?

Comment: I get the $tempPath from a configuration file. properties.getProperty("path");

Comment: Have a look at that property file, I guess the path is wrong there .

Comment: The path I have in the property file is "/home/user/java_correlation_engine/CorrelationFiles/temp.txt". And the query is also getting printed correctly. Only in the execute statement it is causing the error.

Comment: Need to post all code touching $tempPath.  Also, the server this is executing on (the "linux server") is hosting MySQL?  or is MySQL server remote?

Comment: Mysql is hosted in remote windows machine and the file is in Linux server. On answering your question I got my solution. Thanks!